# Linux kernel tracepoint: Symbol undefined when connecting a probe function to tracepoint

Tags: linux, kernel, undefined, symbols, tracepoint

I'm now practicing with Linux tracepoint.
    Basically, I'm trying to make a kernel module where a probe function is defined and connected to a tracepoint("trace_netif_receive_skb" in kernel source file dev.c) in Linux Kernel.
    When I compiled and ran the kernel module on SLES11, it works well. But when I did the same things on SLES12, it complained that the symbol is undefined.
    The kernel module source code is:

```
  1 #include <linux/module.h>
  2 #include <linux/kernel.h>
  3 #include <linux/init.h>
  4 #include <linux/skbuff.h>
  5 #include <trace/events/net.h>
  6 
  7 static void probe(void *ignore, struct sk_buff *skb)
  8 {
  9     printk(KERN_INFO "probe, protocol[0X%04X]\n", ntohs(skb->protocol));
 10 }
 11 
 12 static int __init init_tracepoint(void)
 13 {
 14     if (0 != register_trace_netif_receive_skb(probe, NULL))
 15     {
 16         printk(KERN_INFO "tracepoint init fails\n");
 17     }
 18 
 19     printk(KERN_INFO "tracepoint init succeeds\n");
 20     return 0;
 21 }
 22 
 23 static void __exit cleanup_tracepoint(void)
 24 {
 25     unregister_trace_netif_receive_skb(probe, NULL);
 26     tracepoint_synchronize_unregister();
 27 
 28     printk(KERN_INFO "tracepoint exit\n");
 29 }
 30 
 31 module_init(init_tracepoint);
 32 module_exit(cleanup_tracepoint);
 33 
 34 MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");
```

This is the output on SLES11, no error is reported.

```
suse11-1:~/works/tracepoint # make
make -C /lib/modules/3.0.76-0.11-default/build M=/root/works/tracepoint modules
make[1]: Entering directory `/usr/src/linux-3.0.76-0.11-obj/x86_64/default'
make -C ../../../linux-3.0.76-0.11 O=/usr/src/linux-3.0.76-0.11-obj/x86_64/default/. modules
  CC [M]  /root/works/tracepoint/tracepoint.o
  Building modules, stage 2.
  MODPOST 1 modules
  CC      /root/works/tracepoint/tracepoint.mod.o
  LD [M]  /root/works/tracepoint/tracepoint.ko
make[1]: Leaving directory `/usr/src/linux-3.0.76-0.11-obj/x86_64/default'
suse11-1:~/works/tracepoint # insmod tracepoint.ko
```

This is the output on SLES12, it says: WARNING: "__tracepoint_netif_receive_skb" [/root/works/codes/tracepoint/tracepoint.ko] undefined! And I can find "Unknown symbol __tracepoint_netif_receive_skb (err 0)" in /var/log/messages.

```
suse12-1:~/works/codes/tracepoint # make
make -C /lib/modules/4.4.21-69-default/build M=/root/works/codes/tracepoint modules
make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-4.4.21-69-obj/x86_64/default'
  CC [M]  /root/works/codes/tracepoint/tracepoint.o
  Building modules, stage 2.
  MODPOST 1 modules
WARNING: "__tracepoint_netif_receive_skb" [/root/works/codes/tracepoint/tracepoint.ko] undefined!
  CC      /root/works/codes/tracepoint/tracepoint.mod.o
  LD [M]  /root/works/codes/tracepoint/tracepoint.ko
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-4.4.21-69-obj/x86_64/default'
suse12-1:~/works/codes/tracepoint # 
suse12-1:~/works/codes/tracepoint # insmod tracepoint.ko 
insmod: ERROR: could not insert module tracepoint.ko: Unknown symbol in module
```

I checked the kernel source code of tracepoint framework of both SLES11 and SLES12, the "__tracepoint_##name" defined "include/linux/tracepoint.h" is not exported unless EXPORT_TRACEPOINT_SYMBOL() or EXPORT_TRACEPOINT_SYMBOL_GPL() is called, but I didn't find any place in linux kernel codes where EXPORT_TRACEPOINT_SYMBOL(netif_receive_skb) or EXPORT_TRACEPOINT_SYMBOL_GPL(netif_receive_skb) is called to export symbol __tracepoint_netif_receive_skb. 
Then why I didn't meet the problem on SLES11? And how can I get it work on SLES12?

Answer (score 0):

Use `for_each_kernel_tracepoint` to find target tracepoint and register probe, works for me, good luck.

```c
struct tp_reg {
    const char *name;
    struct tracepoint *tp;
    void *fn;
};

static void each_tracepoint(struct tracepoint *tp, void *priv)
{
    struct tp_reg *regs = (struct tp_reg *)priv;
    int i;
    
    for (i = 0; regs[i].name; ++i) {
        if (strcmp(tp->name, regs[i].name) == 0) {
            if (tracepoint_probe_register(tp, regs[i].fn, NULL) == 0) {
                regs[i].tp = tp;
            }
        }
    }
}

static void unregister_tp(struct tp_reg *regs)
{
    int i;

    for (i = 0; regs[i].name; ++i) {
        if (regs[i].tp) {
            tracepoint_probe_unregister(regs[i].tp, regs[i].fn, NULL);
            regs[i].tp = NULL;
        }
    }
    
    tracepoint_synchronize_unregister();
}

static int register_tp(struct tp_reg *regs)
{
    int i;
    
    for_each_kernel_tracepoint(each_tracepoint, regs);

    for (i = 0; regs[i].name; ++i) {
        if (regs[i].tp == NULL) {
            printk(KERN_ALERT "trace point %s not found.\n", regs[i].name);
            unregister_tp(regs);
            return 1;
        }
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

Sample code:

```c
static void probe_callback(void *ignore, struct pt_regs *regs, long id)
{
    if (id == __NR_execve) {
        char file[100];

        if (strncpy_from_user(file, (void *)PT_REGS_PARM1(regs), sizeof(file)) < 0)
            return;

        printk(KERN_INFO "execve %s", file);
    }
}

static struct tp_reg myreg[] = {
    { .name = "sys_enter", .fn = (void *)probe_callback },
    { .name = NULL }
};

static int __init init_tracepoint(void)
{
    return register_tp(myreg);
}

static void __exit cleanup_tracepoint(void)
{
    unregister_tp(myreg);
}
```